# Picking the right NLP model to tag words from a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

As the title suggests, I am posting here in the hope someone could direct me towards NLP models for tagging words.

To be more concrete, here is what I wish to do. I would like to build a flashcard application using an NLP model that would tag/categorize words.
So let us imagine I have a CSV file with items made of one question (in English) and one answer (in French):

```
+----------------------------
| plane       | avion       |
+-------------+-------------+
| chopsticks  | baguettes   |
+-------------+-------------+
| airport     | aéroport    |
+-------------+-------------+
```

The idea is that the learners would pick a contextual deck (in this example, a deck related to travelling with planes). That deck would be generated by a tag "airport" made by the machine learning algorithm.

And thus, is there any good models I should look to?

Edit:

After much research, I came across NLU which meets many of the requirements I have described above. If you are interested, please have a look at those links: [What is NLP technique to generalize manually created rules in text?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-is-nlp-technique-to-generalize-manually-created-rules-in-text/40500#40500) and [NLP algorithms for categorizing a list of words with specific topics](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40973/nlp-algorithms-for-categorizing-a-list-of-words-with-specific-topics), as well as this repo: [Probase-Concept](https://github.com/ScarletPan/probase-concept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating lists of words related to the same topic, my first thought would be to take a large corpus of (monolingual) text, apply [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) and then collect random top words by topic.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan for the hint, helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could look into sequence-to-sequence models. These model can be used to "translate" text. There is a [nice example in Keras](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq/), where you can straight away build a translation model for `English -> French`.

> This example demonstrates how to implement a basic character-level
> recurrent sequence-to-sequence model. We apply it to translating short
> English sentences into short French sentences, character-by-character.
> Note that it is fairly unusual to do character-level machine
> translation, as word-level models are more common in this domain.

Also note this blogpost ["A ten-minute introduction to sequence-to-sequence learning in Keras"](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

Comment: All right, thanks for that @Peter, I'll have a look now.